# Sitecore Multiple nodes for rendering datasource

Tags: c#, xpath, sitecore, rendering, sitecore7.2

I am using Sitecore 7.2(rev. 140228), I have multiple sites & all of them have their own content store or meta-data. Now I wants to give them choice to select datasource either from own meta-data of other site. Although I know another option to make meta-data global outside of all site but in my case it's not an option.

I have wrote an simple Xpath query:

```
./ancestor::*[@@templatename="Main section"]/*[@@templatename="SiteFolder"]//*[@@templatename="ContentStore"]
```

Which return me valid result in Sitecore rocks that I wants as below

[image]

But when i updated this in my rendering's **data source** field it returns just first instead of both.

[image]

Is there any way to show multiple datasource here.

Thanks ,

Comment: In my experience the datasource location can only have one root item, don't think you can have multiple roots.  Would be good to hear if it is possible by some customisation. In this scenario I open out the root item to be more global (the solution which is not possible for you) so that the user  can choose either data. Question though - if the data is shared between sites - surely it would be better for it to be global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in early verions of Sitecore 7.x - mutliple roots are not supported for datasource selection.

The issue was fixed in Sitecore 7.2 rev 140526. Check reference number 389483 in [Sitecore 7.2 rev 140526 release notes](https://sdn.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20v5/sitecore%20cms%207/releasenotes/changelog/release%20history%20sc72.aspx).

If you cannot upgrade to the next version, you may want to contact Sitecore Support - I had the same issue and they sent me a patch which worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply i had found this solution earlier here 
http://www.seanholmesby.com/multiple-datasource-locations-using-queries-are-back-in-sitecore-7-2-update-2/

but client was hesitating to upgrade but now he is agreed & happy.

Comment: @Marek Musielak, Thanks,
Although i have updated your dll code for 7.2 & it was working fine but creating some other issue related to tree expand & collapse so I contacted to sitecore support & they provided me patch for 7.2.